# $.post does not seem to be firing, but the database is updated anyway(sometimes)?

Tags: jquery, post

So this one is a real head-scratcher. I have some code, like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("span").empty(".error-message");
        if ($("form").hasClass("data")) {
            var formData = [];
            switch (event.target.id) {
                case 'edit-username':
                    formData = $("#edit-username").serializeArray();
                    break;
                case 'select-country':
                    formData = $("#select-country").serializeArray();
                    break;
                case 'select-type':
                    formData = $("#select-type").serializeArray();
                    break;
                default:
                    formData = $("#data-read-form").serializeArray();
            }
            $.post("../php/data_handler.php", formData, function(data) { 
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                if (typeof result.status !== "undefined") {
                    $("#" + result.control + "-error").html(result.message).css("display", "inline-block");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $(".open").attr("class", "closed");
                    $(".modal-overlay").css("display", "none");
                }
            });
```

Here is the HTML for the relevant forms:

```
<div id="username-modal" class="closed">
        <form id="edit-username" name="edit-username" class="data modal-form">
            <label>
            Enter New Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="new-username" class="user-input">
            </label><br>
            <span id="username-error" class="error-message"></span><br>
            <button type="submit" class="save" id="change-username">Save</button><button type="button" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="query-type" value="username">
            <input type="hidden" name="data-verb" value="update-user-data">
        </form>
    </div>
<div id="country-modal" class="closed">
        <form id="select-country" name="select-country" class="data modal-form">
            <label>
            Select Country:<br>
            <select name="country" id="choose-country">
                <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
...
//Proceed to list all recognized countries, I'll refrain from posting all 193 select options
</select>
            </label><br>
            <span id="country-error" class="error-message"></span><br>
            <button type="submit" class="save" id="change-country">Save</button><button type="button" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="query-type" value="country">
            <input type="hidden" name="data-verb" value="update-user-data">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="type-modal" class="closed">
        <form id="select-type" name="select-type" class="data modal-form">
            <label>
            Choose a Page Type:<br>
            <select name="type" id="choose-type">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
                <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
                <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                <option value="People">People</option>
                <option value="Film">Film</option>
                <option value="News">News</option>
                <option value="How-To">How To</option>
                <option value="Education">Education</option>
                <option value="Music">Music</option>
            </select>
            </label><br>
            <span id="type-error" class="error-message"></span><br>
            <button type="submit" class="save" id="change-type">Save</button><button type="button" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="query-type" value="page-type">
            <input type="hidden" name="data-verb" value="update-user-data">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is allow a user to change certain settings by opening a dialog (handled by a separate click event) and submitting the changes using a form submission (some settings require large amounts of additional data to be sent, hence why each setting change has it's own form, hence the need for the switch statement). Now before I actually did have each submit event handled by a separate block of code, before I wizened up and realized I could condense the code using a switch statement instead. Did doing so break my code? I don't know, didn't test it before making the change...but for obvious reasons I'm hoping the switch statement isn't the issue. So here is the actual issue: it is pseudo-working; in that it is working for some settings but not for others. For example, when changing the type or country, the appropriate changes are made in the database, and the updated settings display properly on page refresh. However, when I attempt to change the username, instead of updating the user's username, it simply attempts to load that user's page. i.e. If the username exists in the db it will load that user's page instead of throwing a username already taken error as expected, or in the case that the username is not taken it will throw an Uncaught Type Error: index undefined as I would expect. But this is not what it should be doing; to reference my server-side code--it seems to be running the readUserData function instead of the updateUserData function, but why? Especially since it is running correctly for the country and type settings, but not for username? The code is written the exact same way for each! To make it even weirder, I've set up a breakpoint to determine where the code is breaking and in doing so have discovered that $.post seems to not be firing. But this only adds to the mystery because it doesn't seem to work not only for the username but the country and type as well, so how is it that the country and type are being updated correctly!? I'm so confused...code gurus please help.

Update:
I've tried replacing the switch statement with $(this).serializeArray(); which causes formData to return undefined. Whereas before when I used the switch statement to specify a specific form, formData returned the expected values i.e. {new-username:user-input, query-type:username, data-verb:update-user-data}. In either case, $.post is still not executing.

Comment: Why do you need the `switch`? Just use `$(this).serializeArray()`

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see what parameters are being sent in the AJAX request, and check them against what the script is expecting.

Comment: Without the form HTML and the script, it's hard to tell why it's not working as expected. But it sounds like `serializeArray()` isn't returning all the parameters that are expected for editing the username.